# structuring my mysql table correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a list of businesses and each business could be part of any number of categories. So what I would normally do is have a table 'business' then a table 'categories' and a table 'businesscategories' which would have the id of the business and category so therefore a business could be linked to any number of categories.

However, I wondered if there's a much simpler way of assigning businesses to any number of categories? Just keeping it all to 1 or 2 tables would be brilliant if possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it wouldn't be brilliant. Your original approach is right.

The keyword here is "normalization". Only your original approach presents a normalized model of your data.

Don't worry about having numerous tables. The tables have to accommodate the logical structure of the information, not the other way around.

(If you want, though, you can represent *bounded* data by an enum rather than a category table. But that's a minor decision.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I totally understand the good reasoning behnind having a normalised database. However, the reason I thought about having something like the above is because I want my client to be able to output one CSV file from excel and then dump that into php/mysql and come up with a database on which further searches/actions can be done. Should I stick to the normalised method?

Comment: If the client's Excel data is in a bad logical state, then I'd say you shouldn't try to compromise on the database design because of that. Rather, you should write an appropriate import/export logic (export should be simple via a query). It's your call, but usually the database design should be determined by the logical structure of the data, and everything else should follow from there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice so far; final question is how would I set up my normalised data from a CSV file? Would I need 3 separate CSV files for the 3 separate tables?

Comment: It all depends. Are you the one designing the entire system? Then perhaps yes. Are the CSV files only for exporting and viewing, or do you receive your input data in that format? If you're forced to have a flattened-out single table (i.e. every secretary's first Excel "database"), then you could read it into a temporary table in your DB and then run a validating insertion query on it -- basically, you are reversing the JOIN operation.

Comment: I am designing the entire system and although I could make a special login area where the client can add categories then businesses, and assign categories for each business etc. I would rather have a simpler system, so I was considering using an excel file which they could easily update then every so often simply 'upload' it to the mysql database. Just not sure how to start with that..

Comment: Well, it's certainly *possible*. You can make a restricted Excel file where the dependent columns only allow certain values... the point is that the inverse of a JOIN operation necessarily must be able to validate and reject inconsistent data. If that's acceptable, you can indeed accept flat input data -- as long as it's consistent. But if you're designing all of it, why not make a nice web interface instead?

Comment: Hmmm, good point. I will go back to the drawing board then. Thanks very much for your help!